# Defining a spring-data JPA repository interface for entity with primary key that is also a foreign key in JPA 2.x

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

I have an entity with a JPA 2.x defined primary key that is also a foreign key 
 to another entity (JPA 2.x [allows](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Example_JPA_2.0_ManyToOne_id_annotation) for `@Id` annotations on `@*ToOne` relationship fields):

```
@Entity
class FooOptionalInfo {
    /* ... fields ... */

    @Id
    @OneToOne
    public Foo getFoo() { return foo; }

    /* ... setters ... */
}

@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    public Long fooId;

    /* ... getters/setters ... */
}
```

Spring JPA repository interfaces should extend the `Repository<T, ID>` interface where `T` is the `@Entity` class and `ID` is the entity's `@Id` field, however:

Defining `public interface FooOptionalInfoRepository extends Repository<Foo, Bar>` or `extends Repository<FooOptionalInfo, Long>` results in the same error below upon spring jpa initialization:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This class [class com.example.FooOptionalInfo] does not define an IdClass
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.metamodel.AbstractIdentifiableType.getIdClassAttributes(AbstractIdentifiableType.java:183)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation$IdMetadata.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:253)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:68)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:100)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:199)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 20 common frames omitted
```

**Do I need to revert back to JPA 1.x standards and define both the Entity and the basic id field (`@Id Long fooId; @OneToOne @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(...) Foo foo;` in `FooOptionalInfo`) or is there a way to eat the JPA 2.x simplified annotations and have my spring repository cake as well?**

Comment: I can look up if you still have trouble, but try defining a `Long` ID on `Foo` and using `@MapsId` on `getBar`.

Comment: MapsId [docos](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) say it's meant for EmbeddedIds, is that going to be an issue? Also I was trying to avoid having the primitive id explicitly there altogether (As JPA 2.x suggests you can do) or is this simply causing more hassle than it is worth?

Comment: I've personally never had a problem with it. I also wrote a Groovy AST transform that takes care of adding the ID and all of the annotations for me, so I also don't directly *see* the ID field. ;-) One of these days I'll get it release-ready...

Answer (score 0):

It's a litter strange for the `id` to be the primary and foreign key at the same time. You can accomplish this in another way: define the foreign key in `Bar`.

```
@Entity
class Foo {
    @Id
    private long id;
    // ...
}

@Entity
class Bar {
    @Id
    public Long barId;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="foo_id")
    private Foo foo;
}
```

Comment: `Foo` - in my case - is an optional meta-info table for `Bar`. `Bar` may or may not have an associated `Foo` (0 or 1). Why is it "strange" when I can just use the same foreign key as my primary identifier for the underlying table? I've edited my question to better describe my problem.

Comment: i.e. I don't need to add another identity field to the underlying table in order to uniquely identify the rows there. In a @OneToOne relationship, the foreign key *is* the identity.